# File open in excel version 2013 but not on 2016?

Tags: java, excel, ms-office, attachment

I am sending the html content as excel from my webserver server with the following headers

```
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.xls");
```

I am able to open the file on excel version 2013 but not on 2016. On 2016 version, it says `The file is corrupt and can not be opened` however once I activate `File > Properties > Security> Unblock` the file opens up ? Is there any header or other setting where I can specify to unblock security (or other configuration) so that I am able to open the excel file like I do on 2013 ?

Comment: Have you tried changing to xlsx format?

Comment: @cup i did try that but that does not work too

Comment: I don't have 2016 here to test but there seems to be some good reports of this fix (albeit for Word the settings are the same in Excel).
https://blog.lekman.com/2012/10/remove-protected-view-from-office-2013.html

Comment: Have you tried sending an excel file created in 2016? Would be good to know if this is about the content you are sending - if you generated it, it could actually contain xml errors - or just a header issue.

Answer (score 2):

The security settings are set in Excel: not in the workbook. Check File/Options/Trust Centre. You need to compare the settings in both 2013 and 2016. Possibly External Content or File Block settings.

At a guess, 97-2003 workbooks are blocked.

Comment: Its exactly same.